# Allow user access to one directory in a S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I searched through existing questions and couldnt find an answer.

I want to restrict access to one directory S3 bucket to some user. For example, I have the directory my-bucket/test/123. I put a few images to this directory. Other users should not have access to this directory.
Then I created Bucket policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AddPerm",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789000:user/some-user"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/test/123/*"
    }
]
}
```

But when I tried to open file in browser, I recieved "Access Denied" message.

I tried to use *Deny* effect and *NotPrincipal*. In this case, the files are available to other users.
Please help!

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried to open file in browser"? Did you use the full URL to the file, eg `http://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/test/123/foo.txt`? How did you authenticate to AWS that you were `some-user`? Did you try accessing the object via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 cp` command instead?

Comment: Yes, I use full URL. I did authenticate to AWS with User name and password for AWS console. Also I did authenticate with PHP code.

Comment: Could you please Edit the question and provide more details about how you are connecting to Amazon S3 when you receive the Access Denied message. We need to see how you are authenticating. Please provide code you are using, or a description of exactly how you are connecting and authenticating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need bucket listing permissions on the root prefix (folder) as described in this AWS doc [Writing IAM Policies: Grant Access to User-Specific Folders in an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/):

> Although David should have access to only his home folder, he requires
>   additional permissions so that he can navigate to his folder in the
>   Amazon S3 console. David needs permission to list objects at the root
>   level of the my-company bucket and in the home/ folder.